# "click" event not responding on mobile

Tags: javascript

I have been working on a search process for the Web App I am developing for my business.

I currently have a search field that, when conditions are met, makes a DIV visible that contains suggested matches of the searched term for the user. This all works correctly, except I am having issues with an eventListener responding correctly to mobile "touch". The eventListener hides the DIV when the BODY of the page is clicked anywhere at all. However, on mobile device, I have to specifically touch an input field or other element on the page for it to execute the Java Function.

I would rather that a touch responds the same as a mouse click... and I am able to touch the page anywhere for it to execute the Java Function and hide the DIV. How can I do this?

Disclaimer: I have never written or edited Javascript before this, so what I am currently using is cut and pasted together from many resources.

here is the code:

```
function myFunction() {
    var input = document.getElementById("searchterm").value;

        if (input && input.length >= 2) {

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "searchengine.php",
            data: {input : input},

            success: function(data) {

            if (data){
            document.getElementById("body").addEventListener("click", resultsVisibility);   
            document.getElementById("results").style.visibility='visible';
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = data;
            }

            else{
            document.getElementById("results").style.visibility='hidden';
            }

            }

            }); 

        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("results").style.visibility='hidden';
            return false;
        }
}

function resultsVisibility() {
    document.getElementById("results").style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById("body").removeEventListener("click", resultsVisibility);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to query the `body` tag with this?

```
document.getElementById("body");
```

That would query an element with an `id` attribute of `body`. Not sure what you meant. If you did mean the actual document body, you can refer to that with simply: `document.body`. No querying needed. If you do need an element with an `id` of `body`, then you can change my below code.

**EDIT**: Switched to `div` with an `id` of `body`. Forewarning, you should avoid `id`s and use `class`es instead. I've seen far too many sites have errors thanks to duplicate `id`s. `class`es don't suffer from the same fate.

Just attach a `touchstart` event in addition to your `click` event:

```
(function() {
    var results = document.getElementById("results");
    var fakeBody = document.getElementById("body");
    var resultsVisibility = function() {
        results.style.visibility = "hidden";
        fakeBody.removeEventListener("click", resultsVisibility);
        fakeBody.removeEventListener("touchstart", resultsVisibility);
    };

    var myFunction = function() {
        var input = document.getElementById("searchterm").value;

        if (input && input.length >= 2) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "searchengine.php",
                data: { input: input },

                success: function(data) {
                    if (data) {
                        fakeBody.addEventListener(
                            "click",
                            resultsVisibility
                        );
                        fakeBody.addEventListener(
                            "touchstart",
                            resultsVisibility
                        );
                        results.style.visibility = "visible";
                        results.innerHTML = data;
                    } else {
                        results.style.visibility = "hidden";
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            results.style.visibility = "hidden";
            return false;
        }
    };
})();
```

Also, you should store multiply used elements rather than querying the DOM over and over. Querying the DOM is *slow*. I also took the liberty of wrapping all of your code in an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). This keeps you from having implicit globals.

Comment: I did in-fact mean to use the id="body" because I gave the body DIV that id. I knew that referencing something by id the way I was would work, and I wanted to be sure that wasn't part of any problems I was having. Question: how can I now execute the code you provided above onKeyup. I was using onKeyUp="myFunction()" before, but that now returns an error when using the code you provided. The error is "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: myFunction".

Comment: @inkslinger, stop using attributes to attach listeners. Add another line just as I did with `touchstart`, but make it `keyup` instead.